# What is best method to use responsive style for angular 7 project. I have added css for each component

Tags: css, angular

How to use Responsive Style for Angular 7 Project. I have added CSS for each component. when I have added responsive style in the global file then it's not inherit firstly. Do I need to add a responsive style separately according to each component?

Comment: yes add responsive styles separately.but if it's same style for all the component you can use global style.post your code example

Comment: @MadhawaPriyashantha when I add responsive file globally its not inherit responsive code firstly. in browser inspect its only detect component css first and then responsive.

Comment: can you create a demo with minima code here https://stackblitz.com/

Answer (score -1):

No, don't need to add different style for the responsive you can add media CSS in your style.css. for responsive you use below media CSS:

```
@media (min-width: 1025px) and (max-width: 1280px) {



@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px) {



@media (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 767px) {



@media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px) {
```

Comment: I'm using angular 7 and I do not want  to load all style by globally that effect on performance. I want to load only which component/page open. so i have added style  to each component/page file. when i add responsive code in global file then its not coming firstly.